# Achievements and Total Reputation doesn't match actual Reputation

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

My Stackoverflow rep for today is `155` but the `Achievements drop down` in top bar says `140`.
So, my total rep is messed up. I am 15 rep short.
What could cause this error?

**NOTE** : The answer acceptance points for the question `Syntax Explanation for end keyword` are missing from Achievements + Total Rep score.

[image]

Comment: I would say caching but I've never seen caching affect the reputation tab before

Comment: @Servy Its not showing bogus points in Achievements. It is not showing the rep entry altogether.

Comment: @Servy I don't fully understand the duplicate target; that seems to be about specific entries not matching which makes perfect sense, but this is about day totals

Comment: Just looks like the achievements bar hadn't picked up the latest accept (+15) yet, probably just a transient issue due to caching (those things are rendered separately). Is it correct now?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Nope. No change. I even logged out, cleaned browser cache, logged back in and still the same.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I don't think *your* browser cache has anything to do with it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Well, just in case. I tried it.

Comment: Most likely you deleted then undeleted one of your answers that was later accepted. The action of deleting cause the post to be ignored by the top bar achievements/reputation dialog as already reported in the post I linked to.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't delete or/and undelete any of my answers today.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Do you know of any other instance in which this could happen?

Comment: Nope, there's chance my assumption is wrong of course but those two cases appear to be related and caused by the same bug.

Comment: Seems like SO has partially fixed the problem, now my achievements are matching the reputations earned today BUT it's not reflected in the `total reputation`.

Comment: I see 1,577 in all locations that are exposed to me. Do you see something different somewhere? Where? Or are you expecting 1,592?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yup. I was expecting 1592. +15 was missing from Achievement bar as well as the rep total in top bar. Now Achievement is synced up with rep earned today but not with the total rep.

Comment: Well I suspect that an answer was unaccepted (maybe quickly after accept) and you're not accounting for it or didn't notice. I don't know where the extra 15 is you expect to have. I looked at the graph on [your reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1012097/kirti-thorat?tab=reputation) and painstakingly added up all of the values in the tooltips over every bar, and came up with 1574, plus your base 1 rep, = 1575. The other 2 rep missing, not sure, a down-vote I missed, or two down-votes you placed on an answer that we can't see. Do you have any evidence about this missing 15 rep?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for looking into this. Appreciated! Thats the screenshot that I have as an evidence but i think its fine since my points add up as you say.